# Can jquery Masonry be added to a drupal theme without Masonry modules?

Tags: drupal, responsive-design, themes, jquery-masonry

Is there a way to add [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) jquery to my drupal theme without Masonry modules?Just to add it to the theme files.I'm using lexi responsive theme.I think I must upload masonry.pkgd.min.js to the already  existing js folder , add scripts[] = js/masonry.pkgd.min.js to the info file of my theme and add width: 220px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left; to .node class in my style.css but after that...Can someone guide me step by step please.

Answer (score 0):

Another option you can write PHP code in drupal theme template.php under preprocess_html hook

```
/* Theme Preprocessor */
function <THEME_NAME>_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
global $base_url;
drupal_add_js("<PATH_TO_JS_FILE>", array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'header', 'weight' => 5));
}
```

After adding to template file its very important to clear your Drupal cache.

Comment: no more error js/masonry.pkgd.min.js after many cache clear but nothing happens.I did css the teaser with witdh and float proprety but no masonry effect.bartik is the theme I'm working with - is easy to css and is very responsive unlike other themes.